# How to display application menus only when selected top menu item is clicked in redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am working on Rails 3, Redmine, Redmin Plugin. Following are the codes in init.rb.

```
Redmine::Plugin.register :my_utilization do
  name 'Name'
  author 'Author'
  description 'Plugin Description'
  version '0.0.1'
  url ''
  author_url 'site.com'
  menu :top_menu, :utilization, { :controller => 'utilization', :action => 'index' }, :caption => 'Reports' }
  menu :application_menu, :utilization, { :controller => 'utilization',   :action => 'index' }, :caption => 'Utilization', :if => Proc.new { User.current.logged? }
  menu :application_menu, :project_reports, { :controller => 'project_reports', :action => 'index' }, :caption => 'Projects', :if => Proc.new { User.current.logged? }
  permission :my_utilization, { :utilization => [:index], :project_reports => [:index]}
end
```

Below is the picture displaying top menu and application menu items.

[image]

As shown in image, Home, My page, Projects, **Reports**, Help are the top menu items and **Utilization**, **Projects** are the application menu items. Present application menu Utilization and Projects are displaying when I clicked any of the top menu either Home, My page, Projects, Reports. But I want to display Utilization, Projects application menu only when Reports top menu is clicked.

Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to clarify the problem a bit?  Your paragraph starting with "Here **Reports**..." isn't very clear.  It might also help to include an annotated screen shot using imgur or something (a pic can be worth 1K words).

Comment: @steveklein: Thanks for quick response. I have uploaded pic, please have a look into this.

Comment: Sorry text is way too small to read and I still don't understand the problem.  Can you dump your screen shot in PPT and then annotate the issue on the picture?  Then if you use imgur or a similar site, the resulting image is a lot easier to read.  For instance, see a recent imgur I used to explain a problem on SO:  http://imgur.com/IXFLQbV.

Comment: I guess it is clear now, http://i.imgur.com/W4YnNlH.png

Comment: According to the [Redmine Plugin Tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial), you'll just want a single `menu` line like `menu :reports_menu, :utilization, { :controller => 'utilization', :action => 'index' }, :caption => 'Utilization'` in each submenu definition to tie back to `:reports`.  I believe this should replace the three menu lines in your code above.  Syntax may need tweaking but hope this helps.

Comment: I guess Redmine supports only five menus: and i didnot see reports_menu. But also i will check it and i will update you.

Comment: OK but your screenshot shows a Reports menu which you must have created in Redmine.  Whatever you called it there (in the main menu) is the name you should use in the `:menu` line in both of the submenu definitions to connect it up.  GL!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78216/discussion-between-ror-and-steve-klein).